# How to take and handle object from multiple threads in Java? How to create Multiple instances of Future

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, threadpool

I need to create bunch of JMX connections to different hosts. I'm trying to create these connections in parallel. In this performance is much better now.

I've method to which I'm passing Collection of "host and port" entries. For each entry one connection will be created.

Now I'm submitting this task of creating connections to Multiple threads. But I don't know how to take return and store the connection objects created by threads.

code goes like this,

```
ConnectionFactory.createConnections(collection of hostportEntries)

class ConnectionFactory{

public static CollectionOfConnections createConnections(ListOfHostPorts)
{

   ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

   for(iterate over hostportEntries)
   {
     Future<Connection> future1 = exec.submit(new connCreator(HostPortEntry));

      //Now here, connCreator is implementing Callable Interface and creating connection. and returning it. I'm taking reference of that Returned connection. 
//But how will I take              Multiple Connection objects returned by Multiple threads. I tried to create Future[] but OPTION like that doesn't seem to be there
      // Can anybody help here?????

   }

//if I succeed in getting the objects return then I'll store in one more collection and return those for further use of those connections.

}
```

Comment: You could create a map of host/port as keys and returned futures as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ThreadPool's invokeAll method - it takes a collection of Callables and returns a list of Futures.

Edit: the advantage of using invokeAll over simply submitting your tasks one at a time and putting the Futures in your own list is that invokeAll will return only after all of the tasks complete, so you don't have to keep checking all of the Futures to see if they have completed.

Comment: Actually, `ExecutorService` also has an `invokeAll` method.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGreek Ah, you are correct, I simply looked at the classes `ExecutorService` inherited from when I double checked my comment. Any particular reason you chose to mention `ThreadPool` vs. `ExecutorService` as used in the original post?

Comment: code in original post is invoking newFixedThreadPool - I suppose I could have referenced ExecutorService, and probably should have.

Comment: Fair enough, have an upboat!

Answer (score 1):

Once each thread (your ConnectionCreator) creates a connection, it needs to register the handle to the newly created connection with a singleton of some sort.  If you are running within an EJB container, this is easily accomplished with a session bean.  Essentially, this session bean could become the "connection pool".  Within the connection creator, you could do the following (For brevity, I am excluding exception handling and other things you should already be doing):

```
Inside of ConnectionCreator
============================

// Create your connection
Connection myConnection = doWhateverToCreateConnection();

// Presuming things went fine, get a handle to the session bean.  You could
// also potentially do this through resource injection using Spring or what not.  
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ConnectionPoolBean connectionPoolBean = ( ConnectionPoolBean )ctx.lookup( "java:module/ConnectionPoolBean" );

// Now, register the connection with the pool
connectionPoolBean.registerConnection( myConnection );
```

Then in your ConnectionPoolBean, you hold a collection of connection objects.  You should have register and unregister methods in those objects -- as well as possible getConnection... et cetera.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote - that's a really complicated answer to a fairly simple question. There's absolutely no excuse for bringing a Singleton pattern, let alone EJBs into this discussion.

Comment: To quote the OP:  "But I don't know how to take return and store the connection objects created by threads."  IMHO, I agree with archer that your answer is not correct because he isn't asking about Future<V>.  He is asking how to store the newly created connection object itself outside of the ConnectionCreator.  Basically, OP is asking how to go about creating a connection pool when you are using parallel threads to create connections.  In the future, at least ask for clarification before you downgrade answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) javadoc `Future<V>` has `.get()` method that returns an object of type of `V`. You should invoke that method to receive the result of `Future` execution. It's safe to invoke it from callee thread.

Comment: I believe that OP knows that, they're just asking how to handle more than one at a time.

Comment: it seems he asked `how to take return` I assume he wanna know how to `get` the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to run your connection openers and get them in order of the one who opens connection first :)

So, with your code, it would be something like

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CompletionService<Result> ecs
       = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(exec);

for (HostPortEntry hpe : hostportEntries) { ecs.submit(new ConnCreator(hpe)); }

Collection<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>(hostportEntries.size());
for (int i = 0; i < hostportEntries.size(); i++) {
    // will add the created connections in order of what finish first.
    connections.add(ecs.take().get());
}
return connections;
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

IMPORTANT: you could not use CompletionService and `Executor#submit`. The thing is that your call to `Future#get()` **must** be done in another loop, or you will block your thread until the just submitted callable has finish. So:

```
Collection<Future> connCreatorsFuture = new ArrayList<Future<Connection>>(hostportEntries.size());
for (HostPortEntry hpe : hostportEntries) { connCreatorsFuture.add(exec.submit(new ConnCreator(hpe))); }

Collection<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>(hostportEntries.size());
for (Future<Connection> connection : connCreatorsFuture) {
    // will wait until this connCreator finishes.
    connections.add(connection.get());
}
return connections;
```